# Marshmallow,the MediaMetadataRetriever does not working

Tags: android

On the Marshmallow the MediaMetadataRetriever with OPTION_CLOSEST, `OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC`, `OPTION_NEXT_SYNC`, `OPTION_PREVIOUS_SYNC` does not work.

The `OPTION_CLOSEST` works fine with all versions of Android except Marshmallow. I tried to extract 30fps from video. Below is the code I used:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(33333*i,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

where, i-->1,2,3,...(next frames)

How can I extract 30fps in Android Marshmallow?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed by the Google Team as you can see here
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193194